how to ask a closure to return a borrowing at the end of its scope?
Considering the following function body:

    fn update_acc(&mut self, acc_rub: &Vector3<f32>, _t: u64) -> () {
        let acc = Self::rub_to_frd(acc_rub);

        if acc.norm() < 1.0 {
            return (); // almost in free fall, or acc disabled, do not correct
        }

        let delta_opt = || -> Option<UnitQuaternion<f32>> {
            let uncorrected = self.attitude.inverse().transform_vector(&Self::UP_FRD);
            let delta_opt = UnitQuaternion::rotation_between(&acc, &uncorrected);

            delta_opt
        };

        let dd = delta_opt();
        match dd {
            Some(delta) => {
                self.inconsistency = self.inconsistency * Self::INCONSISTENCY_DECAY + delta.angle();

                match UnitQuaternion::try_slerp(
                    &UnitQuaternion::identity(),
                    &delta,
                    Self::BASE_GRAV_RATIO,
                    0.01,
                ) {
                    Some(correction) => {
                        let new_attitude = self.attitude * correction;
                        self.attitude = new_attitude;

                        {
                            // TODO: verification code, clean up
                            let residual = delta_opt().unwrap().angle().abs();
                            if (residual >= 0.01) {
                                println!("!!!!!!!!!! residual: {} !!!!!!!!!!", residual);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    None => {
                        // TODO: opposite direction, don't know how to correct
                    }
                };
            }
            None => {
                // no error no update
            }
        }
    }

When being compiled, it gave the following error:
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.attitude` because it is borrowed
   --> src/naive_cf.rs:160:25
    |
140 |         let delta_opt = || -> Option<UnitQuaternion<f32>> {
    |                         --------------------------------- `self.attitude` is borrowed here
141 |             let uncorrected = self.attitude.inverse().transform_vector(&Self::UP_FRD);
    |                               ------------- borrow occurs due to use in closure
...
160 |                         self.attitude = new_attitude;
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self.attitude` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
...
164 |                             let residual = delta_opt().unwrap().angle().abs();
    |                                            --------- borrow later used here

This error is very hard to reproduce, if I inline the calls to the closure delta_opt, the error disappear. If I try to reproduce it in a slightly simpler function that also uses self.attitude in a closure, the error also disappear:

    fn dummy(&mut self) -> () {

        let delta_opt = || -> (Option<f32>) {
            let a = self.attitude.inverse();
            Some(a.i)
        };
        match delta_opt() {
            Some(v) => {
                self.attitude = UnitQuaternion::identity();
            }
            None => {}
        }
    }

I have 3 questions:

why is the closure dummy not tampering the borrowing status of self.attitude? What's the difference?
How can I modify the closure delta_opt such that the borrowing of self.attitude is returned when the call to the closure has returned?
How can I rewrite the closure delta_opt to make it an inline expansion? (Namely, the compiler can expand its invocation into its code implementation)


SO is a question and answer site. Note that question is singular, not plural. If you have more than one question, they need to be in separate posts. For more information about how the site works, see the [help].

Why aren't you just inlining the closure?

@cadolphs just don't want to repeat myself

You're typing () way more than necessary.  -> () -> , return () -> return.

Here's what I think happens:
It works with your dummy example because in the dummy example you're only using the closure once. The compiler is smart enough to realize that, so it drops the closure early enough for the borrow to self.attitude that happens in the closure to be released.
In your full example, you have a second call to the closure, in one of the match arms. Because of that, the closure can't be dropped early, which means the borrow to self.attitude is kept alive and assigning to it is an error.

ah, that make a lot of sense, but in the meantime, multiple invocations of a closure will share 1 borrowing? that sounds scary

Why is that scary? The binding for a closure happens when that closure is defined, not when it is run, so for as long as the closure lives, it holds on to its borrows.

I didn't use a "move ||" for the closure, so there should be no new binding, & in this case, all mutable references are used in 1 thread, it's impossible to cause racing condition

@tribbloid Closures has to store their captures somewhere. This somewhere is in their own instance. So you're borrowing self.attitdue from the closure definition until its last call, you can't assign to it in the middle.

@tribbloid It's not (always) about race conditions. It's the fact that your closure holds an immutable reference to self.attitude and therefore, you can't mutate self.attitude anywhere.
